# JQuery how to focus on an input after jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, focus

Hi I want to focus on the input text after loading some data using jQuery, I've tried below but it doesn't work.

```
  $('#load_window').load("q_pages/questions.html #q1", function(){
    $('#q1_input').focus();
  })
```

Comment: Try to select your element like this `$('#load_window').find('#q1_input).focus();`.

Comment: That load selector doesn't seem right. If you put a `console.log()` inside `load()`, is that fired at all?

Comment: @iamdlm yes the console.log is fired.

Comment: @Lapskaus i tried this one but it's still not focusing.

Comment: And `console.log($('#q1_input'))` prints the element?

Comment: @iamdlm yes it does get selected

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle?